# Array Processing (stretching) Method

Tags: java, arrays

I'm looking for a hint on how to solve this or where I am going wrong.

The question is as follows: Write a static method named stretch that accepts an array of integers as a parameter and returns a new array twice as large as the original, replacing every integer from the original array with a pair of integers, each half the original.  If a number in the original array is odd, then the first number in the new pair should be one higher than the second so that the sum equals the original number.  For example, if a variable named list refers to an array storing the values {18, 7, 4, 24, 11}, the call of stretch(list) should return a new array containing {9, 9, 4, 3, 2, 2, 12, 12, 6, 5}.  (The number 18 is stretched into the pair 9, 9, the number 7 is stretched into 4, 3, the number 4 is stretched into 2, 2, the number 24 is stretched into 12, 12 and the number 11 is stretched into 6, 5.)
Test your code with the following class:
import java.util.*;

```
public class TestStretch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = {18, 7, 4, 14, 11};
        int[] list2 = stretch(list);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));  // [18, 7, 4, 24, 11]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list2)); // [9, 9, 4, 3, 2, 2, 7, 7, 6, 5]
    }

    // your code goes here
}
```

This is currently what I have, but it is not quite working correctly... I have a feeling it is how i'm using int i and int j, but i'm not sure what to do to fix it so that it works as intended.

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestStretch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = {18, 7, 4, 14, 11};
        int[] list2 = stretch(list);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));  // [18, 7, 4, 24, 11]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list2)); // [9, 9, 4, 3, 2, 2, 7, 7, 6, 5]
    }
    public static int[] stretch(int[] array){
        int length = array.length;
        int[] newArray = new int[array.length*2];
        for(int i = 0; i< length; i=i+2){
            int j = 0;
           if(array[i] % 2 == 0){
               newArray[i] = (array[j]/2);
               newArray[i+1] = newArray[i];
               j++;
           } else{
               newArray[i] = (array[j]/2);
               newArray[i+1] = (newArray[i] + 1);
               j++;
           }

        }

        return newArray;
    }

}
```

The output I get is:

```
[18, 7, 4, 14, 11]    
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Instead of:

```
[18, 7, 4, 24, 11]    
[9, 9, 4, 3, 2, 2, 7, 7, 6, 5]
```

Comment: "*but it is not quite working correctly*" -- Please [edit] your question to include *how* it is not working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes:

- The loop iterates only until half of the array, skipping elements by 2
- The value of `j` is reset to 0 in each iteration

Also, the algorithm can be simplified:

- For each index `i` in the input, you want to set in the destination at position `2 * i` and `2 * i + 1`.
- The second value to set is simply the original value divided by 2, with integer truncation
- The first value to set is the same as the second, +1 if the division by 2 leaves a remainder

With the above issues corrected, and the implementation simplified:

```
int[] newArray = new int[array.length * 2];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newArray[2 * i] = array[i] / 2 + array[i] % 2;
    newArray[2 * i + 1] = array[i] / 2;
}

return newArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

Three mistakes:

1. `j` should be initialized outside the for-loop
2. we should use `j` to record the new value into the new array
3. we should increment `j` upon every iteration in 2 - and we should increment `i` only by 1 (since we're using `j` to insert two item while we use `i` to iterate the original array):

   ```
   int j = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i< length; i++){
       if(array[i] % 2 == 0){
           newArray[j] = newArray[j+1] = array[i]/2;
       } else{
           newArray[j] = array[i]/2 + 1;
           newArray[j+1] = array[i]/2;
       }
       j += 2;
   }
   ```

Note: giving a variable that holds an array the name "list" might create confusion!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i< length; i=i+2){
```

`length` is the length of the original array, so you iterate only over half of the values because you increase `i` by `2` each step.

```
if(array[i] % 2 == 0){
```

This should be

```
if(array[j] % 2 == 0){
```

And because you define `j` within your for-loop, array[j] always returns `18`. Oh and you set the second element of the tuple to be the higher one while your comment in the code says the contrary should take place.

So a fixed version of your method would look like this:

```
public static int[] stretch(int[] array){
    int length = array.length;
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length*2];
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< newArray.length; i=i+2){
       if(array[j] % 2 == 0){
           newArray[i] = (array[j]/2);
           newArray[i+1] = newArray[i];
       } else{
           newArray[i+1] = (array[j]/2);
           newArray[i] = (newArray[i+1] + 1);
       }
       j++;

    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Avoiding duplicate code:

```
public static int[] stretch(int[] array){
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length*2];
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< newArray.length; i=i+2){
        int val = array[j];
        newArray[i] = (val/2);
        newArray[i+1] = newArray[i];
        if(val % 2 != 0){
            newArray[i]++;
        }
        j++;
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Or using fancy streams:

```
public static int[] stretch(int[] array){
    return Arrays.stream(array)
            .flatMap(elem -> {
                int half = elem / 2;
                int otherHalf = half;
                if (elem % 2 != 0) {
                    half++;
                }
                return IntStream.of(half, otherHalf);
            }).toArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are looping to the old array's length, don't increment `i` by 2.

If `i` increases by 1 each time, we need to figure out how to map the old array's index `i` to the new array's index. It is quite simple: the new array's indices are just `i*2` and `i*2+1`.

Now `j` seems redundant because it always holds the same value as `i`, so you can remove that.

This is the full code:

```
int length = array.length;
int[] newArray = new int[array.length*2];
for(int i = 0; i< length; i++){
    if(array[i] % 2 == 0){
        newArray[i*2] = (array[i]/2);
        newArray[i*2+1] = newArray[i*2];
    } else{
        newArray[i*2] = (array[i]/2);
        newArray[i*2+1] = (newArray[i*2] + 1);
    }

}

return newArray;
```